# cannot access elasticsearch in docker for windows linux containers

Tags: bash, docker, elasticsearch, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am mainly using Bash on windows for subsystem, have docker for windows (Version 17.06.0-ce-win19 (12801)) installed and set to Linux containers.

I am attempting to start it via the following command

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9200 elasticsearch:2.3.5
```

if I attempt to access it via curl on bash, or the browser it is not found.  I have attempted the following:

- localhost:9200
- 127.0.0.1:9200
- (container ip address):9200 [gotten via docker network inspect bridge]
- (my local ip address) :9200 [ifconfig]

---

> - docker logs e727aa95a49d
>
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:50,114][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: your kernel is buggy
>       and you should upgrade
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:50,296][INFO ][node                     ] [Alysande Stuart] version[2.3.5], pid[1],
>       build[90f439f/2016-07-27T10:36:52Z]
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:50,296][INFO ][node                     ] [Alysande Stuart] initializing ...
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:51,046][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Alysande Stuart] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy],
>       plugins [], sites []
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:51,066][INFO ][env                      ] [Alysande Stuart] using [1] data paths, mounts
>       [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space
>       [54.3gb], net total_space [58.8gb], spins? [possibly], type s [ext4]
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:51,066][INFO ][env                      ] [Alysande Stuart] heap size [1007.3mb], compressed ordinary object
>       pointers [true]
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:52,684][INFO ][node                     ] [Alysande Stuart] initialized
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:52,685][INFO ][node                     ] [Alysande Stuart] starting ...
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:52,852][INFO ][transport                ] [Alysande Stuart] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses
>       {0.0.0.0:9300}
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:52,857][INFO ][discovery                ] [Alysande Stuart] elasticsearch/TIf_RDG_SpqbfJ_rJmfizA
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:55,920][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Alysande Stuart] new_master {Alysande
>       Stuart}{TIf_RDG_SpqbfJ_rJmfizA}{172.17.0.2}{172.17.0.2:9300}, reason:
>       zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:55,972][INFO ][http                     ] [Alysande Stuart] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses
>       {0.0.0.0:9200}
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:55,972][INFO ][node                     ] [Alysande Stuart] started
>   - [2017-07-30 01:07:55,999][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Alysande Stuart] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-p 9200` tells Docker to find any available port on Windows (let say `32768`) and map it to the `9200` container port.

You need this:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9200:9200 elasticsearch:2.3.5
```

With `-p 9200:9200` Docker will use always `9200` that will be availble in your localhost: `localhost:9200`